# How can a Sails controller get request history

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

I am developing a website using Nodejs (with Sails & Passport frameworks). I am wondering how a Sails controller get the request history of a user.
For instance, a user requests for '/', but a controller redirects the user to '/signin'. Then the user requests for '/signin' using res.redirect(). So the request history looks like

1. '/'
2. '/signin'.

Now a SignInController handles the request and at the end, it want to redirect the user back to '/'. So the controller should know the history of the user's request. I guess there should be some frameworks which can record request histories and store them using session or something. Could anyone give me some hints about this?

Comment: what you mean by "redirect"?
A http-redirect (like 301)?

Comment: Yes. A http-redirect using redirect()

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if I understood well but what you want to do is to redirect the user to whatever URL he was before a login, right?

To do that you can use the policies (which are executed for all requests, only on the methods you want).
What we do here is save the latest position only (Not the entire history)

In **api/policies/ensureReturnToUrl**:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

  req.session.returnTo = req.url;

  return next();
};
```

The configuration part look like that in **config/policies.js**:

```
  '*': ['passport', 'isAuthenticated', 'ensureReturnToUrl'],
  AuthController: {
    '*': ['passport']
  }
```

You will have to be careful here to put this policy in the right place only. For example, you don't want to have it on you "/signin" methods (That goes against the whole point)

Then, after a successful login, you just have to read the "returnTo" property and redirect the user: (For example in a `AuthController`)

```
if (req.session.returnTo) {
   res.redirect(req.session.returnTo);
} else {
   res.redirect('/');
}
```

Obviously this need to be adapted for your use case but the policies are definitely what you need.

Comment: Thx Aurélien. Your solution is exactly what I am looking for. But just one more question. Actually you add a customized middleware here. But is there any existing middleware I can install via npm which provides this function to avoid reinventing the wheel?

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes, you can directly use this: https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login However, I had to customize a little bit to handle a specific use case with the /register URL so it was "easier" to write my own policy instead. But feel free to choose the best for you :)